# Cannot deploy EVM subnet locally on Avalanche "Error: failed to query network health"

Tags: linux, terminal, virtual-machine, evm, avalanche

I'm trying to deploy EVM subnet locally using avalanche-cli. I'm running it on Ubuntu through WSL.

Running `avalanche subnet deploy somechain -l` and waiting for 2 minutes returns:

`Error: failed to query network health: the health check failed to complete. The server might be down or have crashed, check the logs! rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded`

I tried looking for logs at `/var/log/` but coludn't find any.
What am I doing wrong?

Terminal output for reference:
[image: terminal output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging around with a properly configured Linux environment (i used Docker) it turned out that my problem was related to port forvarding. Some ports were dsiabled by my ISP and the only way to resolve it is to get a static IP and then unlock the required ports with a request to ISP.